# SPF DKIM and rDNS/PTR is set also IP/Domain is whitelisted but still going to spam

Tags: php, email, dns, spf, dkim

I have new domain (3 days old) with proper SPF and DKIM record set, proper hostname set , proper Reverse DNS set. But still its going 30% of the mails to spam.

[image: Mail delivery results]

My Domain is **Multilingualtalents.online** with hostname **server.multilingualtalents.online** with same rDNS.
Has proper SPF and DKIM entries too

### SPF Test

v=spf1 mx a ip4:188.226.170.54/28 a:server.multilingualtalents.online include:server.multilingualtalents.online

### DKIM TEST

v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDk3xU20TCFekf5f+zQOIg02gEsv3A4W94WZL5HdwM7RisJ77vpwfndFXnz30bzlO2Zw9OBixdR+Pc4zt54eZdlI1PALiQTv8e8uw0WPpsP5HaO3qfHN/qmlGQzOJCM0gT6bBI0j49nxGdI15B1ncHtZOrYZxmSuT10skEDDcM/EQIDAQAB

[image: Gmail header check test results]

IP is whitelisted..

I tested everything using mxtoolbox.com

Is there anything that it happens when domain is new ? 
or what can be the actual issue?

Please Help

Thanks

Comment: Where did you get that placement graph? Generally you have no control over inbox placement; major ISPs tend to assume that everything is spam unless *every* recipient tells it otherwise.

Comment: @Synchro  https://ibb.co/cEaDG5 
Its app.glockapps.com